# Volume of high dimension ball

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $v_d$ be the volume of d-dimensional unit ball. Show that:

1. $v_2=2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$
2. $v_d=v_{d-1}I_{d-1}$, where $I_n=2\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{n/2}dx$.
3. $I_n= \frac{n}{n+1}I_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$, and $I_{n-1}I_{n-2}=\frac{2\pi}{n}$.
4. show that $v_d=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(1+d/2)}$.

What I think: for 1 (am I right?), $$v_2=\lambda\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}\}
\\=2\lambda\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:0\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}\} 
\\= 2\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{1/2}dx$$

For 2~5, I am kind of stuck.

Comment: For 2., the intersection of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the plane $x_n = c$ is - for $-1 \leqslant c \leqslant 1$ - a $d-1$-dimensional ball with radius $\sqrt{1-x_n^2}$.

Comment: Far, far better to do $v_d = v_{d-2} I_{d-2}$ and use polar coordinates. http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Cities#Chapter_XV_-_The_Footsteps_Die_Out_For_Ever